# Show $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}})/\mathbb{Q}$ is not a normal extension and find it's normal closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field, separable-extension, normal-extension

I want to show  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}})/\mathbb{Q}$ is not a normal extension and conclude that the normal closure is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}},\sqrt{3-\sqrt{3}})$. After knowing the former, the latter is easy to show.

This entire thing boils down to showing that $\sqrt{3-\sqrt{3}}\notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}})$, and since $$\left(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}}\right)\cdot\left(\sqrt{3-\sqrt{3}}\right)=\sqrt{\left(3+\sqrt{3}\right)\left(3-\sqrt{3}\right)}=\sqrt{9-6}=\sqrt{6}$$ and $\sqrt{3}\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}})$ all that's left to show is that $\sqrt{2}\notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}})$ but I couldn't find a way to do that.

**EDIT**: I am looking for an elegant solution that doesn't use norms, resultants or algebra that is too dirty. The posts mentioned in the comments are not satisfying to me

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3394344/is-sqrt3-sqrt3-in-l-mathbbq-sqrt3-sqrt3?noredirect=1) for "This entire thing", and see also [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432202/when-is-mathbbq-sqrtp-sqrtp-a-galois-extension-of-mathbbq).

Comment: The first post has answers that use terms like "norm" that I haven't learned or uses very non-elegant algebra. I'm looking for a more elegant solution. The second post also doesn't answer my question, and I have already visited it before opening this thread.

Comment: I think that Angina Seng's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3394344/does-sqrt3-sqrt3-in-mathbbq-sqrt3-sqrt3?noredirect=1) is very elegant. The norm also is not difficult or "non-elegant". Moreover the other two answers are very detailed and solve the problem, too. I like the part "Suppose that $\sqrt 2 \in L$. Then $\sqrt 3 \in L$ implies that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{3+\sqrt 3})  =  \mathbb Q(\sqrt 2 ,\sqrt 3)$. " This is a good idea.